# Move multiple object

Tags: python, tkinter

All,

I am writing a code to move multiple balls in a Tkinter window, I know we can easily do this using oops/classes, but I am wondering if we can do this without classes. My current code kind of works but since I use for loops after every iteration one of the balls disappears. can you suggest what's wrong here? and how can I have multiple objects or balls move in a Tkinter window.

```
from tkinter import * 
import random
import time

tk = Tk()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 600, 400
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()


colors = ['red','green', 'blue', 'orange','magenta', 'grey', 'pink', 'yellow',
          'dodgerblue','turquoise']


balls = []

for _ in range(10):
    balls.append(canvas.create_oval(random.randrange(1,10),random.randrange(1,10),random.randrange(50,100), random.randrange(50,100), fill = random.choice(colors)))


  
while True:
    
    x = random.randrange(1,5)
    y = random.randrange(1,5)
    
    
    for b in balls:
        canvas.move(b,x,y)
        pos = canvas.coords(b)
        if pos[3] >=HEIGHT or pos[1] <=0:
            y = -y
        if pos[2] >=WIDTH or pos[0] <=0:
            x = -x
       
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.03)
            
     
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you are moving the balls out of the screen. The term y = -y changes balls position to [-1, -5]. You might try to change both lines `x = -x` and `y = -y` to something else. E.g. `x = x + 0.01` and `y = y + 0.01`. Eventually your code is working then.

Comment: if I don't have an - ve sign they will move out of the screen, -ve sign is for the object to go opposite direction when there is a wall

Comment: You should perform the checking before moving the ball.

Comment: The ball in back always first to disappeared, while ball in front will be last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working. Unfortunately, you didn't mention bouncing balls. The HEIGHT and WIDTH don't help with offset screen. By using `winfo_height()` and `winfo_width()` will solve the problem. As for me, I used a bouncing ball using class instantiate module. And `canvas.move(b,x,y)` is always placed after `if/else` condition block. The balls will go offset and will return to the screen. The balls will be separated at random.

Here is snippet code:

```
x = random.randrange(1,55)
y = random.randrange(1,55)
  
while True:    
    for b in balls:
        #canvas.move(b,x,y) 
        pos = canvas.coords(b)
        if pos[3] >=canvas.winfo_height() or pos[1] <=0:
            y = -y
        if pos[2] >=canvas.winfo_width()or pos[0] <=0:
            x = -x
        canvas.move(b,x,y)
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Result:

[image]

You can change value from 55 to higher to suit your need.

Comment: you can change  speed how faster you want to go time.sleep(0.05)